# Why does margin:-4px create a horizontal scrollbar in HTML and how to fix it?

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I have a `<div>` element and inside it there is a grid row element from semantic UI. I made the width to 100% but there is a little space appearing on all sides of the row element. So how to remove it? I used margin:-4px to remove the white space but it creates a horizontal scrollbar instead.

```
<div>
  <Grid.Row style={{height: '400px', backgroundColor: '#444444'}} 
   className="noprint">                            
   </Grid.Row>
</div>
```

and here the css I used:-

```
div{
  margin: -10px;
}
```

Comment: It works fine for me without  your additional style. here is a code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/0vxxv0kqjl

Answer (score 0):

Try `padding: 0` on your row element and remove the negative margin.

Comment: did you tried as inline style? Like style={{height: '400px', backgroundColor: '#444444';padding: 0}}  ?